# My python program works on Linux but not on Widows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, image-processing

So my program compares images and deletes any that are the same, renaming the original to how many were deleted. This program works fine on my Linux (ubuntu) but when used on my Windows 8 laptop I get the error at the bottom, any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures/desktop.ini'
```

(there is more to the error code if you need it, also I import os, send2trash, pil, shutil and tkinter to use with the script)

```
import os
from PIL import ImageChops, ImageDraw
import PIL.Image
import shutil
from send2trash import send2trash
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Cupcake 3.0")

paths = Entry(root, width = 50, borderwidth = 5)
paths.grid(row = 2, column =2, columnspan =3)
path = paths.get()


def add():
     end_image = PIL.Image.new(mode = "RGB",size = (200, 70), color = "red")
     end_image.save(paths.get() +"/zzz999.png")
     files = os.listdir(paths.get())
     files.sort()
     image1 =files[0]
     counter = 1
     im1 = " "
     for file in files:
          original_file_name, file_ext = (os.path.splitext(file))
          if delete == 0:
               ofn, fe = (os.path.splitext(image1))
               if image1 == file:
                    pass
               elif image1 != file:
                    im1 = PIL.Image.open(paths.get() + "/" + image1).histogram() #the image to be compared too
                    im2 = PIL.Image.open(paths.get() + "/" + file).histogram()#file for comparison
                    if im1 == im2:
                         send2trash(paths.get() + "/" +file)
                         counter = counter +1
                    elif im1 != im2:
                          os.rename(paths.get() + "/" + image1, paths.get() + "/" + ofn + "_X" +str(counter)+ fe)
                          counter = 1
                          image1 = file
                    else:
                          print("something went wrong")
          else:
               addd = input("Enter in the text you wish to be added/removed (can not contain blank spaces): ").strip()
               new_name = "{}{}{}".format(original_file_name, addd, file_ext).strip()
               os.rename(path + "/" + file, path + "/" + new_name)
     print("Job Complete")
     send2trash(paths.get() + "/zzz999.png")


welcome = Label(root, text = "Welcome to Cupcake 3.0")
welcome.grid(row = 0, column =2, columnspan =3)

l1 = Label (root, text = "Please enter the path to your folder: ")
l1.grid(row = 1, column =2, columnspan =3)

paths = Entry(root, width = 50, borderwidth = 5)
paths.grid(row = 2, column =2, columnspan =3)
path = paths.get()

d = IntVar()
Radiobutton(root, text = "Add", variable = d, value = 1, anchor = W).grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = W)
Radiobutton(root, text = "Remove", variable = d, value = 2,anchor = W).grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = W)
def_question = d.get()

l2 = Label (root, text = "Enter text you want removed (leave blank if n/a): ").grid(row = 6, column = 2)
rem = Entry(root, width = 50, borderwidth = 5)
rem.grid(row = 7, column =2, columnspan =3)
remo=rem.get().strip()

de = IntVar()
c = Checkbutton(root, text = "Do you wish to delete duplicate files?", variable = de)
c.grid(row = 8, column =2, sticky = W)
delete = de.get()


def run():
     #print(d.get())
     #print(def_question)
     if d.get() == 1:
          add()
     elif d.get() == 2:
          remove()
     else:
          print("I don't understand your command")

def remove():
     files = os.listdir(paths.get())
     files.sort()
     for file in files:
          original_file_name, file_ext = (os.path.splitext(file))
          #print(remo)
          new_name = original_file_name.replace(rem.get(), "").strip()
          os.rename(paths.get() + "/" + file, paths.get() + "/" + new_name)
     print("Job Complete")


submit = Button(root, text = "Run", command =lambda: run())
submit.grid(row = 9, column =2)


root.mainloop()
"

Thats my entire program
```

Comment: Your code is probably trying to read the desktop.ini file which, I guess, is automatically created by windows. Excluding this file from getting read as an image file should do the trick. Also, please paste your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i edited the post to have the whole code.

Comment: Pillow cannot open .ini-files. Please read the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html) to see what files it has support for. If your script just loops over all files in a directory, then you must filter out the files it doesn't support.

Comment: awesome thank you, for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to filter out the files which are not identified as images by PIL. Something like this might work for you

```
def image_filter(filename):
    file_path = os.path.join(paths.get(), filename)
    try:
        im = PIL.Image.open(file_path)
        im.verify()
        im.close()
        return True
    except: # you can handle PIL.UnidentifiedImageError here
        return False

def add():
    ...

    files = os.listdir(path)

    # filter out the files which are not images
    files = list(filter(image_filter, files))

    files.sort()
    image1 = files[0]

    ...
```